# didexit region not firing in android beacon

Tags: android, ibeacon-android

I have an app that will detect Ibeacons using android beacon library

I am able to detect beacons in entry region .But the exit region code is not all working.

1.First i will detect all the beacons around my app
2.Will start monitoring each beacon

```
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            albeaconMnager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {

                @Override
                public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(
                           Collection<org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon> beacons,org.altbeacon.beacon.Region arg1) {
                           if(beacons.size()>0)
                           {
                              try {
                                       albeaconMnager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new  org.altbeacon.beacon.Region("Regionid", beacons.iterator().next().getId1(), beacons.iterator().next().getId2(), beacons.iterator().next().getId3()));
                        } catch (RemoteException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch bl
                           e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

            albeaconMnager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {

                @Override
                public void didExitRegion(org.altbeacon.beacon.Region arg0)                  {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i("tAG", "Exited Beacon!"+arg0.getUniqueId());   
                }

                @Override
                public void didEnterRegion(org.altbeacon.beacon.Region arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                  connectToAppHandler(arg0.getId1().toString(),"entry");



                }

                @Override
                public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state,
                        org.altbeacon.beacon.Region arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
            });
            try {
                albeaconMnager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new org.altbeacon.beacon.Region("Regionid", null, null, null));
                //final Context context = this.getApplicationContext();

                } 
                catch (RemoteException e)
                    {  

                    }
            }
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems in the code block below.  The `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` method gets called approximately once per second when beacons are visible.  Inside that method, a new `Region` is defined matching the *first* detected beacon, and monitoring is started on it.

Two problems:

1. Monitoring is started once every second with the same region identifier (the first parameter to `Region`), effectively *restarting* monitoring on the region defined for that beacon.  Because monitoring is restarted for a single region every second, it is impossible to have a region exit fire as long as any beacons are visible.  Exiting a region happens when beacons within the defined region have not been seen for 10 seconds.
2. The way the code block uses beacons.iterator.next() to access a beacon will get only the first beacon in the ranging callback.  If multiple beacons are visible, this may change from one method callback to the next, causing non-deterministic results.

   ```
          @Override
           public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(
                      Collection<org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon> beacons,org.altbeacon.beacon.Region arg1) {
                      if(beacons.size()>0)
                      {
                         try {
                                  albeaconMnager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new  org.altbeacon.beacon.Region("Regionid", beacons.iterator().next().getId1(), beacons.iterator().next().getId2(), beacons.iterator().next().getId3()));
                   } catch (RemoteException e) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated catch bl
                      e.printStackTrace();
                   }


               }

               // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           }
       });
   ```

Rather than start monitoring inside the `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` callback, I suggest simply changing the code to start monitoring once at the same time ranging is started.  Like this:

```
albeaconMnager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new org.altbeacon.beacon.Region("Regionid", null, null, null));
albeaconMnager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new org.altbeacon.beacon.Region("Regionid", null, null, null));
```

Comment: I need to fire entry and exit and entry events for each beacon in my range.If start monitoring a region by putting null values is it possible to find which beacon is entered the region and which is exiting ??